# Huge postgresql database restore

Tags: postgresql, restore, space

I am trying to restore a huge postgresql database but I cannot recover all the indexes due to lack of space. Can I change the location of temporary files?

HD SDD status after partial loading of DB

[image: df -h]

The article below seems a first aproximation to work this issue.

'''
https://cloudinfrastructureservices.co.uk/install-postgresql-on-centos-stream-9-server/
'''

Comment: Define: "huge" database. That could mean anything, really... one person's "huge" is the next person's morning fractional ETL run.

Comment: The largest table in the database has more than 350 millon records

Comment: Assuming a 2KiB row size, that's only ~716GiB. You can run that off a Raspberry Pi and a $150 Samsung SSD...

Comment: If I use a 500GiB SSD in the clud, it´s working nice. But I crated a 650GiB (SSD) virtual machine in VirtualBox, and I have that problem.

Comment: If this is in a VM then what's the problem? Just nuke it and start over.

Comment: The problem I get is that not all indexes are crated becouse of lack of space. But if you see the picture, it seems enough space

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257280/discussion-between-juan-salvador-and-dai).

Answer (score 1):

Just get a bigger disk.

If the creation of an index fails, for example due to lack of disk space, PostgreSQL will clean up the partially created index.

If that's more than a play system, it would be a good idea not to have the database data on the root file system.